# PHP Files upload count says 1 when should be 0

Tags: php

I have a simple html form element to upload files:

```
<input id="item_image" type="file" name="item_image[]" multiple/>
```

Which accepts multiple files. However, when I count how many, it reports one, even when none are present. If I add files it reports correctly, so if I add two, it reports two.

This is how I'm counting:

```
$blah = count($_FILES['item_image']['name']);

echo "number is $blah";
```

Why is this? Is there a better way to count?

Comment: There will always be at least one submitted with the form field, even if you leave the field empty. If you have it empty, you will most likely get an error of the type `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` (4).

Comment: No, there are no errors until I try a `for each`, which is why I need to count first to know whether to `for each` or not

Comment: @Anant `$blah = count($_FILES['item_image']);` gives 5 every time, regardless

Answer (score 1):

PHP is moronic when doing multi-file uploads. A single file upload gets the structure

```
 $_FILES['name_of_file_input'] = array(
      'name' => 'kittens.jpg',
      'type' => 'image/jpeg'
      etc...
```

while a multi-upload gets:

```
$_FILES['name_of_file_input'] = array(
   'name' => array(
        0 => 'kittens.jpg'
        1 => 'catnip.exe'
   'type' => array(
        0 => 'image/jpeg',
        1 => 'much/fun'
```

Even if no files are uploaded, you still get the `name`, `type` etc.. sub-arrays, because you specified `[]` in the input name.

Having a `<input type="file">` and then not uploading a file STILL produces a $_FILES structure, with an `['error']` of `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`:

```
$_FILES['name_of_file_input'] = array(
    'name' => array(''),
    'type' => array(''),
    'error' => array(4)
    etc..
```

Comment: +10 for explanation. I am on the way to post something similar. but you did it.

Comment: Ok.... but, even if I `count($_FILES['item_image']['error'])` I still get 1 as the answer if I add a file - you haven't really answered my question

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` and see what you're getting.

Comment: and whether or not you include a file doesn't matter. NO file and ONE file still produce a count of `1` - because that's one file, or a non-file with "no upload performed" error.

Answer (score 0):

Even when the file is not uploaded, `$_FILES` will be present (due the file input field), to display the file upload state.

Most values will be blank except `error`:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

)
```

A better checking is to use the `error` key (`4`, in the above output means `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`):

```
if(UPLOAD_ERR_OK == $_FILES['item_image']['error'][0])){
    // File uploaded!
} elseif(UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE == $_FILES['item_image']['error'][0]){
    // No file uploaded!
} else {
    // Some error ocurred!
}
```

Please, see the [Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: even if I `count($_FILES['item_image']['error'])` I still get 1 as the answer if I add a file

Comment: Yes, and like I stated, you should not rely on this to check if file is present or not, but in the error code.